# Something wrong when using multi-threads with sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, sqlalchemy

My requirement is to save mysql tables to csv files. For running it in parallel, I want to use a thread pool to execute multiple `to_csv` this function at the same time in order to dump many tables in parallel. Here I reproduced the issue and implemented the code like below:

```py
import concurrent.futures
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://user:passwd@host:3306/')
conn = engine.connect()

db = 'db_enterprise_0'
table1 = 't_enterprise_0'
table2 = 't_enterprise_1'
table3 = 't_enterprise_2'
filename1 = '/data/test_threading1.csv'
filename2 = '/data/test_threading2.csv'
filename3 = '/data/test_threading3.csv'


def to_csv(db, table, filename, limit=None, delimiter=','):
    sql = f'select * from {db}.{table}'
    proxy = conn.execution_options(stream_results=True) \
      .execution_options(net_write_timeout=3600) \
      .execution_options(max_allowed_packet=67108864).execute(sql)
    outcsv.writerow(proxy.keys())
    while 'batch not empty':
        batch = proxy.fetchmany(10000)  # 100,000 rows at a time
        if not batch:
            break

        for row in batch:
            outcsv.writerow(row)

executor.submit(to_csv, db, table1, filename1)
executor.submit(to_csv, db, table2, filename2)
executor.submit(to_csv, db, table3, filename3)
```

#### The problem:

What the odd thing was it was not able to write data into csv successully, it wrote an **empty content** instead! Although there were csv files created, the content was **empty** or only the **header inside.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 20 Sep 18 10:05 test_threading1.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  0 Sep 18 10:05 test_threading2.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  0 Sep 18 10:05 test_threading3.csv
```

What's the problem with my code? I guess there might be some problem at `conn.execute(sql)`. So what's the exact reason for that? Or is there any other ways for dumping MySQL tables to csv with `sqlAlchemy` in parallel?

Thanks in advance. Appreciate if anyone can give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: Connections are not thread safe.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Hi IIja, I just read tables, not any other actions, it should be thread-safe?

Comment: Some driver implementations might have thread safe connections that support concurrent execution, but the norm is that they are not. Also the SQLAlchemy `Connection` object is not thread safe as is, but requires that you guard access to it: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection

Comment: after reading your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769299/is-connection-pool-in-sqlalchemy-thread-safe, I think if I can use connection pool with ThreadPoolExecutor  to achieve it?

Comment: If using threads, you could and should just checkout a new connection in each thread – in your case in each call to `to_csv()`. The engine and its connection pool is thread-safe and will handle the situation correctly, i.e. serve each thread its own connection.

Comment: got it. thanks a lot for your advice. BTW, is there any snippet for that, I couldn't find it on official document. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the guide from @Ilja Everilä  , I solved it with multiprocessing, but not the multithreading.

Here is the code:

```py
def run_in_process(db, table, filename, delimiter=','):

    file_ = open(filename, 'w')
    outcsv = csv.writer(file_, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    engine.dispose()

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        sql = f'select * from {db}.{table}'
        proxy = conn.execute(sql)

        outcsv.writerow(proxy.keys())
        while 'batch not empty':
            print('batch')
            batch = proxy.fetchmany(10000)  # 100,000 rows at a time
            if not batch:
                break

            for row in batch:
                outcsv.writerow(row)
    file_.close()


p1 = Process(target=run_in_process, args=(db, table1, filename1))
p2 = Process(target=run_in_process, args=(db, table2, filename2))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p.join()
```

#### Reference:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing

[Is connection pool in sqlalchemy thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769299/is-connection-pool-in-sqlalchemy-thread-safe)