# Connection per request , issue with concurrent query execution

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-connection, flask-sqlalchemy

Following is how my SQLAlchemy based Database accessing class is structured in general. There is flask wrapper APIs, which uses these.

I am getting quite a few exceptions of several kinds with this structure. Specifically :

A webservice 'X' uses the function fooBar. If this service gets more than one call **concurrently**, I get the following exceptions :

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1631, in commit
>       raise exc.InvalidRequestError("This transaction is inactive")
>   InvalidRequestError: This transaction is inactive

I also get the following randomly in between :

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid cursor state (0) (SQLFetch)')

Not to mention several deadlocks and rollbacks happening all over.

I get a sense that there is perhaps something wrong in the way I am creating connection. It looks like same connection is getting used across all requests.

Would appreciate if someone could direct what is wrong with this code structure and any other general comments about it are also welcomed.

```
class DBHandler:

 def init(self):        
    try:        
        self.engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10000}, echo=True)

        self.connection = self.engine.connect() 
    except:
        print 'Not connecting to AWS Database'

 def foo(self, skuID):
    try:
        transaction = self.connection.begin()           

        query = "Update Master_SKU SET SKU_Stage = '3' WHERE SKU_ID = ?"            
        results = self.connection.execute(query,skuID)
        transaction.commit()

        return True
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        return None

 def fooBar(self):
    try:
        transaction = self.connection.begin()           

        query = "SELECT * FROM Master_SKU"          
        results = self.connection.execute(query)
        transaction.commit()

        return True
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        return None
```

---

Edit :

Alternate approach :

Does this makes sense ?

```
def fooBar(self):
    try:
        tempConnection = self.engine.connect()
        transaction = tempConnection.begin()

        query = "SELECT * FROM Master_SKU"

        rows = tempConnection.execute(query).fetchall()                      
        transaction.commit()
        return True
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        return False
```

Comment: Seems like you are not closing the opened connection

Comment: You're sharing a connection between threads/some other concurrent workers. Don't do that. Connections are not thread-safe. Each thread/worker should have its own connection.

Comment: @llja I do use the same connection, but create a separate transaction per thread `transaction = self.connection.begin()` . You think that won't suffice?

Comment: It wont suffice. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734792/are-transactions-in-sqlalchemy-thread-safe

Comment: @llja I have done an edit. Can you please see if this is what you are suggesting. Also, if so, please post it as an answer, would be easier for me to mark it if it works out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're opening connection too soon (`self.connection = self.engine.connect()`).
At this point you've opened a connection and you're not doing anything with it.
Probably what is happening under the hood is that database opens a connection for you and creates a lock. Until you've closed it, you cannot perform other transactions (e.g. `UPDATE`). This happens a lot, for example, in PostgreSQL. Try this idiom:

```
connection = self.engine.connect()
# ... perform work
connection.close()
```

Also, see related issue: [python sqlalchemy + postgresql program freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778942/python-sqlalchemy-postgresql-program-freezes).

Comment: I really don't see the number of connections to the DB increasing constantly with use of my code. Wonder if `.commit()` or `.rollback()` automatically close the connection after the call.

Comment: I dont think the problem is that there are too many connections. One is enough to lock table/tables so that UPDATEs will fail. I would check if there are any idling connections when you're opening a transaction

Comment: If I use the web services, making sure there are no two calls at the same time, all works fine. I see no issues at all, even in update queries. Issue happens only in case I do concurrent calls.